# How can I see when a package was released/updated using `apt`?

Tags: debian, files, apt

I want to install the "file" package using `apt`, since my Docker container is missing the `file` command. Before installing, I'm checking the package details (see below).

How can I see the date these packages were released/updated? Their descriptions say that they are supported for 5 years, but that makes no sense, when I cannot see when they were released/updated?

Also, why is `apt` listing two "file" packages? Which one of those would be installed, when I run `apt install file`?

```
root@eca1fcd5655a:/mnt/dotnetcore# apt show -a file
Package: file
Version: 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3
Priority: important
Section: utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Christoph Biedl <debian.axhn@manchmal.in-ulm.de>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 81.9 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libmagic1 (= 1:5.32-2ubuntu0.3)
Homepage: http://www.darwinsys.com/file/
Task: minimal
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 22.1 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: Recognize the type of data in a file using "magic" numbers

Package: file
Version: 1:5.32-2
Priority: important
Section: utils
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Christoph Biedl <debian.axhn@manchmal.in-ulm.de>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 81.9 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libmagic1 (= 1:5.32-2)
Homepage: http://www.darwinsys.com/file/
Task: minimal
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 22.1 kB
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
Description: Recognize the type of data in a file using "magic" numbers
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The five-year support term applies to supported packages in [Ubuntu LTS releases](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) as a whole; when individual packages are released or updated doesn’t matter. Packages in the `main` repository receive publicly-available security updates for five years after the initial release of the distribution.

To see the latest changes to a package, look at its changelog:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/${package}/changelog.Debian.gz | head -n 20
```

In this case, `/usr/share/doc/file/changelog.Debian.gz`.

You can also view a changelog without installing the package by using `apt changelog`:

```
apt changelog file
```

or look at the release information [on the package’s page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file).

`apt show -a` lists two packages in your case because there are two versions available, one in the main repository, and another in the updates repository. The version which will be installed is the greater of the two, the version from the updates repository.

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. So there are two repositories, "main" and "update", because new updates always go in the "update" repository until a newer update is released, after which the older update replaces the version in the "main" repository?

Comment: There’s a `main` suite (alongside `universe`, `restricted` and `multiverse`); the `main` suite has a `release` repository, which contains the packages as they were when the distribution was released, and `updates` and `security` repositories, which contain updated packages. AFAICT release repositories are never updated; successive updates overwrite previous updates in the update repositories. `file` has had three updates in the Bionic repositories, and only the last one is available there.